# Ignore string data that does not match a certain format when calculating "min" with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame column 'datetime' with the values in this format:

`'2016-08-01 13:43:35'`

I would like to find the min and max values. The problem is that some of the rows are missing time values so they look like this:

`'2016-07-29  '`

How can I exclude the rows with missing data when calculating the min and max?

Here is how I'm finding the min value:

```
min_ = df['datetime'].min()
```

The minimum value that I'm trying to find is the earliest date/time combination where both are included. So for example in from my data:

'7/29/2016 11:02:38' would be the desired value.

Comment: What are the minimum values you are trying to find?

Comment: @Nikil, I've edited my question above to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values that have a specific format to datetime, and the remaining ones will be NaT. If you take the minimum on the resulting series, it will ignore NaTs.

```
df['datetime'] = ['2016-08-01 13:43:35', '2016-06-01 13:43:35', '2013-08-01 13:43:35',
                  '2016-07-29  ']
df
Out: 
              datetime
0  2016-08-01 13:43:35
1  2016-06-01 13:43:35
2  2013-08-01 13:43:35
3         2016-07-29  


pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
Out: 
0   2016-08-01 13:43:35
1   2016-06-01 13:43:35
2   2013-08-01 13:43:35
3                   NaT
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').min()
Out: Timestamp('2013-08-01 13:43:35')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your date strings have a decreasing order of magnitude (i.e. year --> month --> ...), there is actually no need to convert toe datetime objects.

Also, since your date strings should all be fixed-width, all you really need to do is drop the rows with missing values and then compare the date strings directly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2016-08-01 13:43:35', '2016-06-01 13:43:35', '2013-08-01 13:43:35', '2016-07-29  ']})

min_dt = df[df.datetime.str.len() == 19].min()
print min_dt
# 2013-08-01 13:43:35

max_dt = df[df.datetime.str.len() == 19].max()
print max_dt
# 2016-08-01 13:43:35
```

[EDIT] Since the topic of running time came up in the comments, I did some %timeit testing and found that keeping the date strings (instead of using `to_datetime`) is about 20x faster. But both methods are acceptably fast for 1M rows.

```
print data[0:4] # Data list of 1M date strings.
# >>> ['01/01/2015 00:00:00', '01/01/2015 00:05:00', '01/01/2015 00:10:00', '01/01/2015 00:15:00']

print len(data)
# >>> 1047870

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': data})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': data})

%timeit -n5 d=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').min()
# >>> 5 loops, best of 3: 5 s per loop

%timeit -n5 df2[df2['datetime'].str.len() == 19].min()
# >>> 5 loops, best of 3: 232 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In my case your solution is returning multiple values from other columns in the dataframe but not the value from the 'datetime' column.

Comment: It is not a very expensive operation. It's a one-time operation and it would take only seconds on a dataframe that has 10m rows. On the otherhand, once converted, it is faster to find minimum/maximum of datetime variables. And it is much more easier to aggregate or summarize when the type is datetime.

Comment: I remember profiling one my projects last year and discovering that the bulk of running time was a due to a `to_datetime` process. I will have to look into it.

Comment: @ayhan After playing with `timeit`, I learned something today. When you use `format` argument, `to_datetime` performs roughly 50x faster. I've always thought of `to_datetime` as being expensive because I first used it on millions of rows without the `format` specified! I will edit my answer.

Comment: And just because I timed it, I will add my method is about 20x faster when tested on a 1-million column dataframe (4.8 seconds vs 0.22 seconds).

Comment: I think it is highly affected by the number of invalid entries. When I time it with 1m entry (25% invalid) the result is 280ms vs 478ms. When only the first 3 are valid, it is 226ms vs 1.16s. There can also be differences due to versions may be? http://imgur.com/a/WDgbp

Comment: Interesting. I am using 0.18.1. I get results inline with your picture. This suggests that the number of unique entries also has an impact. In my example, I took a text file with 100k unique date strings and copied them 10x times.